# Como ligar as coisas que baixei do composer com o meu projeto?

Tags: php, composer

Eu baixei as coisas do Composer(ñ sei se ta td certo). Baixei o exe composer lá do site oficial e o git bash. Aí eu queria usar um projeto do github que é o OPEN BOLETO. Ai eu coloquei aquele require "kriansa/openboleto": "v1.0" no composer JSON que tá em C:\Users\Administrador. O meu projeto tá no C:\wamp64\www.

Então eu digitei composer update aí deu tudo certo lá, mas como eu coloco junto com meu projeto pra eu poder usar?

E outra pergunta, não tem uma maneira mais manual de fazer isso, tipo só com mexendo alguns arquivos e usando include ou require do PHP?

Comment: ALGUEM ME AJUDA AI PFV

Comment: ME AJUDA AI GALERA